# How to display a scrolled navbar when page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, navbar

So I got this script :

```js
$(function() {
  var header = $(".header-nav");
  $el = $(".header_logo a").clone().addClass('cloned');

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 50) {
      header.addClass("scrolled");
    } else {
      header.removeClass("scrolled");
    }

    if (scroll > 50) {
      $el.appendTo(".header-logo");
    } else {
      $('.cloned').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

It makes the navbar fixed on scroll and clone logo and reset it on top page.

But if I refresh page at the middle, navbar isn't displayed cause it displays only on scroll.

Is there a way to fix that please?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could pull out the callback function from scroll. Give it a name like `checkScrollHeader`. Use that in the scroll arguments `scroll(checkScrollHeader)`. Call `checkScrollHeader` on load?

Comment: Check the `scroll` value on page load and do stuff based on that value.

Answer (score 0):

As evolutionxbox suggested you should move your code into a function and call it both on scroll and on load like this:

```
$(function() {
  var header = $(".header-nav");
  $el = $(".header_logo a").clone().addClass('cloned');
  myScroller();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    myScroller();  
  });

  function myScroller(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 50) {
      header.addClass("scrolled");
    } else {
      header.removeClass("scrolled");
    }

    if (scroll > 50) {
      $el.appendTo(".header-logo");
    } else {
      $('.cloned').remove();
    }
  }
});
```